# How to create bulk records in rails(V4.2.3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have tried to crate multiple records at once, but getting error.

examples:

```
  Job.find(5601).job_permissions.insert_all(recruiter_id: recruiter.id, job_access_action_id: job_access_action_id.id)

  Job.find(5601).job_permissions.bulk_insert(recruiter_id: recruiter.id, 
  job_access_action_id: job_access_action_id.id)
```

errors:
NoMethodError:   JobPermission Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `job_permissions`.* FROM `job_permissions` WHERE `job_permissions`.`job_id` = 5601
undefined method `insert_all' for #JobPermission::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x0055c4da1ceea0

Comment: `insert_all` introduced in `Rails 6`, you can refer [this](https://blog.saeloun.com/2019/11/26/rails-6-insert-all.html#before-rails-6) article for how to achieve it in Rails 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call insert_all on an ActiveRecord class, not association_proxy as you do now, so:

```
Job.insert_all([{recruiter_id: ..., {recruiter_id: ...}])
```

Answer (score 0):

The `create` method takes also an array as a parameter.

```
JobPermission.create(
  [
    { job_id: job.id, recruiter_id: recruiter.id, job_access_action_id: job_access_action_id.id },
    ...
  ]
)
```